# Out of memory error when transposing rows to columns

Tags: mysql, out-of-memory, group-concat

I have a query like

```
create table table1 (unique i1 (col1,col2))
select
  col1,
  col2,
  group_concat(distinct case when type=3 then value end order by value desc separator ',') col3,
  group_concat(distinct case when type=4 then value end order by value desc separator ',') col4,
  group_concat(distinct case when type=5 then value end order by value desc separator ',') col5,
  ...
  group_concat(distinct case when type=N then value end order by value desc separator ',') colN
from table2 
group by col1,col2
order by null
```

It runs fine but if N is "too high" (more than 50 columns) it gives the out of memory error on a 64bit server with 16GB RAM

What variables should I check ?

Comment: documentation says-
Message: Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space

Comment: Start by decreasing max_connections.